# How do I render the values returned from a computed property in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code in the template of my component:

```
      <th scope="row">{{@order.id}}</th>
      <td>Name: {{@order.customer_name}}
      </td>
      <td>Delivery address: {{@order.address}}
          Products in order: {{@order.products}}
          Items: {{items}}
      <td>{{@order.total_price}}$</td>
</tr>
```

And I have my computed property which should return and render each product name in the array of objects returned from the database:

```
items: computed('order.products', function() {
        let products = this.get('order.products');
        products.forEach(product => {
            for(let i=0; i<products.length; i++){
                return console.log(products[i].name);
            }
        });
    }),
```

And when I run the following everything works okay and the names are displayed in the console like this:

```
Cheese on toast
3 Pizza
2 Macaroons bowl
```

But when I try to remove console.log and just return products[i].name, nothing seems to be returned. Am I missing something or trying to render it on my page incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the snippet, I'm presuming you want to return only the name of the products from the `items` computed property. If so, then there is some issue here is with the handling of loops and not with the actual computed property.

So in your case, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to filter out only the name of the product from the products array.

```js
items: computed('order.products', function() {
  let products = this.get('order.products');
  let productNames = products.map((product) => {
    return product.name;
  });
  return productNames;
})
```

Also, the computed property only retain the value that was returned from the definition. Thus you need to return the value explicitly as shown in the above snippet (`return productNames`).